# Android Engineering Mode

Tags: custom-roms, motorola-defy, acer-iconia-a500

Is there a way to change between User and Eng mode on android devices? More specificity the Motorola Defy (2.2.2) and the Acer Iconia A500 (4.0.3) I need access to tools like dev tools. I dont mind if I have to root the DEFY.

Comment: What precise capabilities do you need?

Comment: Developers Tools etc

Comment: Network analysis as well

Comment: Android is designed so that development can be done on a secured device.  Build an apk set to be debuggable and you can use run-as to get a shell running as the apk userid.

Comment: Are you referring to developer tools for Dalvik application, NDK application, or for modifying the OS itself?

Comment: there are several network analysis tools on the Play market, such as Shark (based on Wireshark on desktop), they do need root access.

Comment: I have root access so thats no problem. I just need monitoring software for the network, I wanted to use the one with ADT but I guess that's not happening. Thanks.

Comment: This answer may help you out for determining what's different between the modes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14767336/198348

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot, that is done at build/compile of the source of the said Android version whatever that may be.

When the source gets compiled via

```
. build/envsetup.sh
```

This is setting up the environment, and that reads in the potential devices via ***BoardConfig.mk*** within each *device/product* directory.

Its when `lunch` gets executed, the menu shows like this

```
$ lunch

You're building on Linux

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
     1. full-eng
     2. full_x86-eng
     3. simulator
     4. zte_blade-eng
     5. zte_blade-userdebug

Which would you like? [full-eng]
```

The above is the example of building the ROM for the Zte Blade, notice how *userdebug* and *eng* is prefixed!

Comment: While this is how it is set, it's not necessarily fully *fixed* to that setting.  Changing some of the ro. system properties in the built image - or even setting ones that haven't been set yet on a running device - can substantially alter the behavior of the system.  The results may not however be stable.

Comment: So there possibly is a way to change this?

Comment: Yes, if you can write to arbitrary flash partitions.  But you don't necessarily need to change the "mode" of the system, it may be enough to alter the specific things keyed to that which you want, for example install some tool for obtaining a root shell.